# Simple python communication class error?

Tags: python, inheritance

Hi i am having some trouble passing variables/doing functions from other classes,

Right now I have something like this,

```
class 1(3):
    def hi():
       print 'class 1'

class 2(3):
    def hi2():
       print 'class 2'

class 3:
    def hi3():
       print 'class 3'
```

Lets say, from class 1 I would like to execute a function from class 2, How can I go about doing this?

I have been Googling this for awhile, and haven't had much success (except for finding images of snakes)

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hint for your next question: You should better name your example classes `A`, `B`, `C` etc. as `1`, `2`, `3` are number literals and technically can’t be used as names.

Comment: The way you ask your question suggests that you might not be clear on the distinction between classes and objects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if class 3 needs functions from both class 1 and class 2 you could do a double inheritance:

```
class one:
    def funct1(self):
        print 'I am defined in class one'
    self.data1 = "one"

class two:
    def funct2(self):
        print 'I am defined in class two'
    self.data2 = "two"

class three(one, two):
    def funct3(self):
        print 'I am defined in class three'
    self.data3 = "three"
```

then any object that is created of class three will be able to call funct1, funct2, and funct3.  Also this object will have it's own version of self.data1, self.data2, and self.data3.

```
ob_3 = three()
ob_3.data1
```

prints 'one'

```
ob_3.funct1()
```

prints 'I am defined in class one'

Now, on the other hand, if you want a function of a sub-class to call a method of a superclass, that can be done:

```
class one:
    def funct1(self):
        print 'class one'

class two(one):
    def funct2(self):
        one.funct1(self)

ob2 = two()
ob2.funct2()
```

prints 'class one'

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`1` doesn't have access to `2`'s methods; `2` is on a different inheritance chain.

You can call the raw function from the method with an instance of `1`, but don't do that. Fix your inheritance chain instead.

Answer (score -1):

Class 3 is the base class and Class 2 is the child class. You are trying to call a child class function from a base class. This doesn't seem right. This is not trivially possible.

Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I guess my code is really really bad, because this is how it is structured.